# Does a residential address get re-classified as commercial if it used to register a one-person-company?

Tags: business, india

An independent consultant working from home in India wishes to incorporate as a one-person-company to cater to clients who won't contract with individuals. Will his residential address get/have to get re-classified as commercial (under *The Karnataka Shops and Commercial Establishments Act 1961* [pdf](https://www.indiacode.nic.in/handle/123456789/7609?view_type=browse&sam_handle=123456789/2485#:%7E:text=India%20Code%3A%20KARNATAKA%20SHOPS%20AND%20COMMERCIAL%20ESTABLISHMENTS%20ACT%2C%201961&text=Long%20Title%3A,in%20shops%20and%20commercial%20establishments.)) if it is used as registered address for the one-person-company?

More information in response to comments:

State: Karnataka

100% remote consulting

No separate office.

Nature of business: Consulting on digital transformation.

Comment: This might be better asked at SE:Law.

Comment: In which Indian state is the premises? Will clients visit or is all the consulting carried out remotely? Is there a separate office etc set aside *exclusively* for the business or will it be a shared domestic area?

Comment: Also, what is the nature of the business? The Karnataka Shops and Commercial Establishments Act 1961 was amended (in 2001) to include some exemptions for Information Technology services.

Answer (score 1):

No, it would be the other way round: If you are at a residential address, you may not be able to run a business that interferes with other residential addresses. It would depend on exactly what you are doing - if your work involves clients visiting and your neighbours complain, you may have to stop doing this.

Comment: Can you tell us from which passage of Indian law you got that information?

Comment: @Philipp I agree that would be nice, and could prove surprising, but this would be the default understanding of how zoning is defined.

Comment: Different Indian states often have there own nuanced legislation so a complete answer will/may depend where the premises is located.

Comment: Exactly. "Stupid" examples that do have no client visits at all are i.e. an IT contractor - he may bed a business by law, but he may not even work out of his address.